# android emulator problem with scale display to real size

Tags: android, android-emulator

android emulator doesn't start when i check the scale display to real size checkbox.any idea why would this happen ?
This only happens when i try to lunch it from eclipse but when i open it with cmd with the scale switch it works just fine.

Comment: do you get any error messages?